# Php Zend with AWS ElastiCache

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

Hi i have an app with php zend framework, i setup an AWS ElastiCache as follow on my zend app

Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initMemcache()
{
    if (extension_loaded('memcache'))
    {
        // Configure caching backend strategy
        $cacheBackend = new Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached(
            array(
                'servers' => array(
                    array(
                        'host' => 'xxxx.yyyy.qqq.rrr.cache.amazonaws.com',
                        'port' => '11211'
                    )
                    // Other servers here
                ),
                'compression' => true,
                'compatibility' => true
            )
        );

        // Configure caching frontend strategy
        $cacheFrontend = new Zend_Cache_Core(
            array(
                'caching' => true,
                'cache_id_prefix' => 'MyApp_',
                'write_control' => true,
                'automatic_serialization' => true,
                'ignore_user_abort' => true
            )
        );

        // Build a caching object
        $memcache = Zend_Cache::factory($cacheFrontend, $cacheBackend);

        Zend_Registry::set('cache', $memcache);
    } else {
        // Handle a non-existent extension here
    }
}
```

And on my controller :

```
public function fetchfrontAction()
{
    $cache = Zend_Registry::get('cache');

    $catid = $this->_getParam('catId');

    $business = new Application_Model_Mapper_BusinessMapper();
    $businessReviewMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_BusinessReviewsMapper();
    $count = 5;
    if (!$result = $cache->load('dataset')) {

        $result = $business->getFetchByCategory($catid,$count);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {

            $result[$i]['business_name_url'] =  $result[$i]['business_url'];
            $userBusinessReviews = $businessReviewMapper->getBusinessReview($result[$i]['business_id'],1);

            if(!is_null($userBusinessReviews)){
                $result[$i]['user_business_reviews'] = $userBusinessReviews;
            }
            $userImg = $this->view->getLoginUserImage(
                $result[$i]['user_business_reviews'][0]['social_id'],
                $result[$i]['user_business_reviews'][0]['login_type'],null,null,square);
            if (!is_null($userImg)) {
                $result[$i]['user_img'] = $userImg;
            }
        }
        $cache->save($result,'dataset');
    }

    $this->_helper->json($result);
}
```

Now the issues is it works without any errors, how can i test whether it really do cache from AWS? Is there a method for me to compare how long does it with and without using cache? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing would be to put an `else` clause on the `if (!$result = $cache->load())` and use `Zend_Log` to log a cache-hit.

Also, I imagine that AWS gives you some management console to inspect/manage the content/activity of the cache. But just thinking out loud on that particular point.